# NSTimer not invalidating in iOS 7, when navigation to new view in iPhone

Tags: ios, sdk, nstimer

I am facing some issue related to `NSTimer`. I need to show a `UIButton` at the bottom in timeframe of 5 seconds. I implemented `NSTimer` functionality and it showing button in that time. However when i navigate to a new `View`. I need to stop that `NSTimer` or invalidate. I have done that in `- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated`. However `NSTimer` is still being executed. Its not been stopped at any time.Below is my code.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self._sizeNowButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height+70, 320, 44)];
    [TLStylesheet useTurquoiseStyleForButton:self._sizeNowButton withText:NSLocalizedString(@"Size Now", nil) withFontSize:BUTTON_BOTTOM_FONT_SIZE];

    [self._sizeNowButton addTarget:self action:@selector(sizeNowClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:self._sizeNowButton];

    SEL tSelector = NSSelectorFromString(@"aTimer");
    self._aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:tSelector userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}


-(void)aTimer
{
    self._tTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(showButton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)showButton {

    if([self._sizeNowButton isHidden] )
    {
        self._sizeNowButton.hidden = NO;
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(self._sizeNowButton .frame.origin.x , self._sizeNowButton .frame.origin.y - 44, self._sizeNowButton .frame.size.width, self._sizeNowButton .frame.size.height);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom
                         animations:^{
                             [self._sizeNowButton  setFrame:newFrame];
                         }
                         completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, 320, 44);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                         animations:^{
                             [self._sizeNowButton  setFrame:newFrame];
                         }
                         completion:nil];

        self._sizeNowButton .hidden = YES;
    }
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self._tTimer invalidate];
    self._tTimer = nil;
    self._sizeNowButton = nil;
}
```

Comment: how did you clear this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are instantiating `self._aTimer` but invalidating `self._tTimer`.

As you appear to trigger two different timers (`_aTimer` and `_tTimer`), you will want to disable both in your `viewWillDisappear:`.

```
if (self._aTimer)
    [self._aTimer invalidate];
self._aTimer = nil;
if (self._tTimer)
    [self._tTimer invalidate];
self._tTimer = nil;
```

Comment: I set self._aTimer to NO, its been only called once and inside -(void)aTimer we are testing one scenario.If scenario is false than _tTimer is been called. I have implemented self._aTimer in disappear still its been called.

Comment: I am entirely unsure on what you are trying to explain here. Anyways, go ahead and check if... 
1. ...`viewWillDisappear:` is ever called?
2. ...`self._aTimer` actually is not nil when `viewWillDisappear:` is invoked?

Comment: viewDidDisappear: is calling every where. I have put the breakpoints and tested, it is been called.self._aTimer is set to nil, however not sure whether it is nill or not. I am making NSTimer nil inside viewDidDisapper not inside viewWillDisappear:

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I have tried all that things, however its not been working.

Comment: I think there is one third party library using CFRunLoop, and in debugger its showing CFRunLoop is causing NSTimer to run continuously. Can we stop this CFRunLoop.

Answer (score 0):

#### try this:

start timer like this

```
self. _tTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(showButton) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self. _tTimer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[self. _tTimer fire];
```

and stop like this-

```
if (self. _tTimer)
{
    [self. _tTimer invalidate];
    self. _tTimer = nil;
}
```

Comment: I tired this still not working, NSTimer still running, I have checked in entire source code, we are using NSTimer only in that particular class.

Comment: are you sure debugger goes inside `viewDidDisappear` method?

Comment: Yes it is going inside viewDidDisappear. I tested this more than tons from morning.

Comment: I think there is one third party library using CFRunLoop, and in debugger its showing CFRunLoop is causing NSTimer to run continuously. Can we stop this CFRunLoop.